# I can't read from a file using iwebHostEnvironment but I can read it if I specify the file path explicitly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I can read a file if I specify the file path using the uncommented code but if I try to do the same thing using IWebHostEnvironment, I am not able to do it.
[image]

IWebHostEnvironment is the path to wwwroot.

The error is:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Comment: what is the value of your "this.iwebHostEnvironment" ?

Comment: Please don't show code as an image. [Edit] your question and put just copy and paste source into it, formatting it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

To troubleshoot the issue, you can debug the code to check if the generated path is as expected.

Besides. you can try the following code snippet.

```
string locl = Path.Combine(this.iwebHostEnvironment, @"Templates\Manifest\defaultManifest.yml");
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Fei Han, hey thanks. youve helped me in a previous question as well.